# how to merge two android apps with each running on seperate tabs of merged app

Tags: android-manifest, android, android-xml

I have two android projects,i want to merge those 2 apps into 1 app and i want each of them to run in different tabs of the merged app.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

From developer.android.com: "Every Android application runs in its own process, with its own instance of the Dalvik virtual machine."

You can't have two separate apps running in the same app.  That's why they were separated in the first place.

However, you can have apps communicate with each other and pass data between the two.  But, only one app can be displayed at a time (though it can display information from another app).